# How to use previous the field not null in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have code in formula field like this:

> IF{CDJ.AC3} = "C3" THEN LOCAL STRINGVAR X:={CDJ.AccountCode3};
>
> IF{CDJ.AC4} = "C3" THEN LOCAL STRINGVAR X:={CDJ.AccountCode4};
>
> IF{CDJ.AC5} = "C3" THEN LOCAL STRINGVAR X:={CDJ.AccountCode5};
>
> IF{CDJ.AC6} = "C3" THEN LOCAL STRINGVAR X:={CDJ.AccountCode6};
>
> IF{CDJ.AC7} = "C3" THEN LOCAL STRINGVAR X:={CDJ.AccountCode7};
>
> IF{CDJ.AC8} = "C3" THEN LOCAL STRINGVAR X:={CDJ.AccountCode8};
>
> IF{CDJ.AC9} = "C3" THEN LOCAL STRINGVAR X:={CDJ.AccountCode9};
>
> IF{CDJ.AC10} = "C3" THEN LOCAL STRINGVAR X:={CDJ.AccountCode10};
>
> LOCAL STRINGVAR Z:=X

the current output is:

```
ACCOUNT CODE
"NULL"
"NULL"
  C3
"NULL"
"NULL"
```

I want to display in footer like this:

```
ACCOUNT CODE
  C3
```

My problem is the output display is :

```
ACCOUNT CODE
"NULL"/bkank
```

Comment: Can someone help me?

Comment: I can't see a relation between your data and your formulla. Where are you using the AccountCode Field in your formula? Plz I need the structure of your databse to help you

Comment: you shouldn't declare a variable every time... declare at start of the code and then use as it is till end... now where is the formula placed and where are you trying to display

Comment: Thank for response guys i solved my problem. :)